# No mapping found for / GET / swagger

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, springfox

I am trying to configure swagger for a project but I receive an error infinite times:

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /project1/api/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui" 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /project1/api/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui" 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /project1/api/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui" 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /project1/api/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui" 
................
```

I have a multi project layer. The structure is :

ProjectName

-- project1

```
  --setting.gradle

  --build.gradle
```

-- project2

```
  --setting.gradle

  --build.gradle
```

--setting.gradle

In each build.gradle I have this dependencies:

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
```

The SwaggerConfiguration class is :

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/");
    }
}
```

And also i have a WebConfigure class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Slf4j
public class WebConfigure extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return new AuthorizationInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Adding interceptor [{}]", AuthorizationInterceptor.class.getName());
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

If I try to access http://localhost:8090/project1/api/swagger-ui.html I receive this error:

[Swagger error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntC4u.png)

Comment: have you tried without the 'project1' in the url?

Comment: Can you add also the server.servlet.context-path?

Comment: server.servlet.context-path=/project1/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "/api" from the server.servlet.context-path .

Somehow the swagger is in conflict with that part.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working on http://localhost:8090/project1/swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Infinite call to **swagger-ui/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui**

There was an invalid swagger api endpoint(which was existing before, later deleted) open in chrome and it was continuously trying to hit the wrong endpoint. It took sometime for figure out. Once I closed the chrome tab, the infinite call stopped.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1815#issuecomment-530881584